# How to create one of those "xxx says xxx 1,000,000,000 times" videos in a command line?

Tags: video, script

For example, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PmQfGzHRqZw

I have looked up basic command line video editing tools and none of them seemed to do the thing I wanted.

I would like to be able to easily control how many divides I make.

Both CMD and Bash are fine.

Comment: Show what you already tried and tools you using to manage video

Comment: @Alex I looked up basic command line video editing tools and none of them seemed to do the thing I wanted.

Comment: Did you tried `ffmpeg` ?

Comment: How am I supposed to use `ffmpeg` to do this?

Comment: Use scaling/resizing of original video than use overlay. [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233832/merge-two-video-clips-into-one-placing-them-next-to-each-other) may help for start